# How to run one asynchronous function when second one is finished?

Tags: jquery, ajax, asynchronous, jsonp

I have problem with two functions. I want `chcekResults` run only when `callAPI` is finished.

My click event:

```
$("a#showA").click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    chceckResults(callAPI(apiKey));
});
```

and functions:

```
var Count = 0;
var ContractsArray = new Array();


function callAPI(yourAPIKey){
var enquiry = URL + yourAPIKey;
//alert(enquiry);
$.ajax({
 url: enquiry,
 type: 'GET',
 dataType: "jsonp",
 jsonp: "callback",
 jsonpCallback: "jsonpCallback2",
 complete: function (response, responseCode) {
 },
 success: function (json) {
     $.each(json.Contracts, function (index, contract) {
        // alert("Count before increament : " + Count);
        // alert(contract.ContractCode);
         ContractsArray[Count] = contract.ContractCode;

        // alert("Count after increament : " + Count);
        // alert("ContractsArray[Count]: " + ContractsArray[Count]);
         Count++;

        });
    }
 });
}

function chceckResults(){
alert("Count value in chceckResults : " + Count);
  for(var i = 0; i <= Count; i++){
    alert("ContractsArray[" + i + "]: " + ContractsArray[i]);
  }
}
```

I want `chcekResults` run only when `callAPI` is finished. How can I do that?

Comment: BTW, is `chceckResults` a typo? Shouldn't it be `checkResults`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want chcekResults run after callAPI is finished, there's several possibilities, it's run after callAPI is successful (I guess this is what you really wanted), or callAPI failed, or both.

Since callAPI is making an ajax call, so you can put chcekResults in the success callback of the ajax.

Such that:

```
$.ajax({
  url: enquiry,
  type: 'GET',
  dataType: "jsonp",
  jsonp: "callback",
  jsonpCallback: "jsonpCallback2",
  complete: function (response, responseCode) {
  },
  success: function (json) {
  $.each(json.Contracts, function (index, contract) {
    // alert("Count before increament : " + Count);
    // alert(contract.ContractCode);
    ContractsArray[Count] = contract.ContractCode;

    // alert("Count after increament : " + Count);
    // alert("ContractsArray[Count]: " + ContractsArray[Count]);
    Count++;
   });
   // --------------------- Edit Begins -------------------------
   chcekResults(...);   // This is run after ajax response returns.
   // --------------------- Edit Ends -------------------------
  }
});
```

This is the quick way of doing it, if you want to make it more generic, you could pass the chcekResults as a callback to the ajax, so that if this callback is defined, run it, if not, ignore. This way, you can use this ajax with or without callback.

Answer (score 2):

Just call the `chceckResults` function from within the `callAPI`'s success handler:

```js
success: function (json) {

    chceckResults();

    $.each(json.Contracts, function (index, contract) {
        ContractsArray[Count] = contract.ContractCode;
        Count++;
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Call `checkResult` in your `callAPI` `success` callback.
`Success` is called once the function has returned.